# How to link an application to a computer or a server?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, url, database-connection

I'm french (so sorry if I make mistakes) and new here, and a novice on XCode development. I have a simply problem:

My application needs to load data from a folder on my computer (or a server) to the device (my iPhone) thanks to the Internet. But I don't understand how to know the URL's address of my computer ?

If I understand, I need something like that:

```
NSURL *serverFile = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mycomputer.com/myfolder/data.txt"];
NSString *documentsFile = [NSString stringWithContentOfURL:serverFile];
```

But how to know or create this URL address ?

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: If you have a domain name, it would be that name.  If not, you could perhaps use your IP address.  It sounds like what you're asking is, "How do I run a server?"  Which is a *very* broad topic.  In general, you'd expose a service of some kind and the address to your computer (plus the port number for the service, if non-default) would reach that service.  There are also router and firewall considerations of course.

Comment: plus your computer must have static IP address

Comment: Or you can use a dynamic DNS service such as dyndns.org

Comment: Also consider using virtual dedicated/private server (VDS/VPS) or shared hosting.

Comment: Ok, I will do this. Thanks all !

Comment: Ok so I have a static IP, but how my NSURL must be look like ? I try "myIP/Users/MyUser/Documents/data.txt" but it return nothing...